# Local and World Coordinates of GUI elements on Game Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` that is created on screen, in Unity 2D mode.

The co-ordinates of the `GameObject` is `(3, 3)`. In the script attached to the `GameObject`, I have the following `OnGUI()` method:

```
void OnGUI() {
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(renderer.bounds.min.x, renderer.bounds.min.y, renderer.bounds.max.x, renderer.bounds.max.y), "")) {
        Debug.Log ("My Position: " +  this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

But when I run the Unity project, the `GUI.Button` is created at the left top corner of the screen, instead of exactly covering the `GameObject`. Is the reason because of the difference of local and world co-ordinates?

How do I create a `GUI.Button()` exactly over the Game Object ?

---

**Update:** After reading @0Andrea's answer, I updated the code. Problem persists:

```
private Vector3 worldPos;

void Start () {
    worldPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
}

void OnGUI() {
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(worldPos.x, worldPos.y, 1, 1), "")) {
        Debug.Log ("My Position: " +  this.transform.position.x + ", " + this.transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

The `GUI.Button` is still locating at left top corner of the screen, instead of over Game Object. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

In Unity GUI elements always work in Screen space. It's described here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html under **Position**: *All UnityGUI controls work in Screen Space, which is the resolution of the published player in pixels.* So it doesn't matter where your GameObject is placed in the scene the rendered GUI is independent of that. Also you don't need to create the GameObject in "2D mode".

As described by 0Andrea you can use a camera transformation to calculate the GameObject's coordinates in screen space by using

```
Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
```

(instead of **WorldToViewportPoint**).

Unity 4.6 will be released with an additional new GUI System called uGUI. With this system you will be able to create GUI elements in world space. http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/28/overview-of-the-new-ui-system/. If you are in urgent need of such a system there is NoesisGUI or NGUI which you can buy in the asset store.

Comment: Excellent! I can get the world position now, but how can I get convert the local size to world size?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GUI elements are represented in viewport coordinates.
I would convert the coordinate system of the gameObject from world coordinates to viewport ones, this way:

```
Vector3 viewPos = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
```

and, then, place the GUI button with respect of these new coordinates. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried. The problem persists. See my updated question.